# Convergence of MLE for i.i.d. sample with PDF $f(x\mid\theta) =\theta x^{\theta-1} 3^{-\theta}I_{(0,3)}(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference

> Given $(X_n)_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with pdf $$\ f(x\mid\theta) = \frac{\theta\ x^{\theta-1}}{3^{\theta}}I_{(0,3)}(x)$$ where $\ \theta > 0$. Using the WLLN, show that the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) converges to $\theta$ in probability.

**My progress:** By definition, $$L(\theta\mid x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i\mid\theta) = \frac{\theta^n(x_1\ldots x_n)^{\theta-1}}{3^{n\theta}}$$ From there, taking derivative of $L(\theta\mid x)$ with respect to $\theta$ and setting it equal to $0$ to solve for $\theta$, I found that the MLE of $\theta$ is $$\hat\theta_n= \frac{n}{\ln(\frac{3^n}{x_1\ldots x_n})}$$ But I could not see how the MLE converges to $\theta$ using WLLN. I tried dividing both numerator and denominator by $n$ to get: $$\hat\theta_n=\frac{1}{\ln(3) - \frac{\ln(x_1\ldots x_n)}{n}}$$ 
On the other hand, $E(x_k) = \frac{3\theta}{\theta+1}$ for every $k$, but it's not true that $\frac{\ln(x_1)+\ln(x_2) + \ldots + \ln(x_n)}{n}\rightarrow E(\ln(x_1))$ in probability.

**My question:** Could anyone please give me some hints on this problem? Did I get the wrong MLE? I reviewed my computation several times and could not find error though.

Comment: "but it's not true that $\frac{\ln(x_1)+\ln(x_2) + \ldots + \ln(x_n)}{n}\rightarrow E(\ln(x_1))$ in probability" Why do you think so?

Comment: As a side remark, why not show the strong consistency using the SLLN?

Comment: I worked it out by assuming it's true, and I did not get $\theta$ at the end. Considering that if it's true, then $E(ln(x_1)) =\frac{1}{3^{\theta}}\int_{0}^{3} \theta x_{1}^{\theta} ln(x_1) dx_1 = \frac{3^{\theta}}{\theta+1}$ (using integration by parts, with the fact that the pdf of $ln(x) = \frac{\theta x^{\theta}}{3^{\theta}})$. Plugging this one into the original expression, the final result is not equal to $\theta$.

Comment: @zhoraster: could you please show how to use that? Considering that the difference in SLLN and WLLN is only in terms of convergence in probability v.s almost sure convergence, but they all converge to $E(ln(x_1))$, which does not give us what we want at the end (if my algebraic steps are correct).

Comment: @Did: did you get the same MLE of $\theta$ as I did above?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did: could you help me show the convergence then? I'm quite stuck now...:P

Comment: @user177196 convergence in probability of $\frac{1}{n}\sum\ln(x_i)\to E(\ln(X))$is a consequence of the weak law of large numbers applied to $\ln(X).$

Comment: @user177196 For the whole thing, it's probably best to first write $\hat\theta = -\frac{1}{\overline{\ln(x/3)}}$ (where the overline denotes a sample mean) and then compute that $E(\ln(X/3))= -\frac{1}{\theta}$ and apply WLLN

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: did you read my comment (3rd post from the top)? I did try that convergence by carrying out the computation for $E(ln(X))$, but I got $E(ln(X)) =\frac{3\theta[(\theta+1)ln3 - 1]}{(\theta+1)^2}$. This does not give my MLE for $\hat{\theta} = \lambda$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: I don't see how you could rewrite my expression for $\hat{\theta}$ in the OP as what you suggested. Could you please help explain what is your notation in the denominator? Also, where does the $E(ln(X/3)) - \frac{1}{\theta}$ come from?

Comment: @user177196 see my last comment. The integral you should compute for  $E(\ln(X/3))$ is $\int_0^3 \ln(x/3) \frac{\theta x^{\theta-1}}{3^\theta}dx$ and the answer is $-1/\theta$. The rewrite is cause $\ln(x_1x_2\ldots x_n/3^n) = \sum_i \ln(x_i/3)$... just rules of logs. The bar is a sample mean and the answer to your last question is that was a typo that's now corrected

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: the pdf of $ln(X/3)$ should be $\frac{\theta x^{\theta}}{3^{\theta}}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55556/discussion-between-spaceisdarkgreen-and-user177196).