# MLE of $\theta$ and its expected value given pdf $f(x|\theta) = \frac{3x^2I}{\theta^3} I_{(0,\theta]}(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference

Given $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d random variables with $\ f(x|\theta) = \frac{3x^2}{\theta^3}\ I_{(0,\theta]}(x)$, $\ \theta > 0$. Find the MLE of $\theta$ and its expected value of the MLE.

**My attempt:** $L(\theta|x) = \frac{3^n(x_1\ldots x_n)^2}{\theta^{3n}}$ for $x_i\in (0,\theta]$ for all $\ i\ =\ 1,\ldots, n$. Thus, $\frac{d}{d\theta} L(\theta|x) = -3^{n+1}(x_1\ldots x_n)^2n\ \theta^{-3n-1}$. Since $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in (0,\theta]$ and $\theta > 0$, $\frac{d}{d\theta} L(\theta|x) < 0$. Therefore, $L(\theta|x)$ only achieves its global maximum at $\theta = 0$ (unreasonable, since $\ \theta > 0$). We conclude that the MLE of $\theta$ does not exist. But if it does not exist, then the same thing is true for its expected value.

**My question:** Did I get a wrong conclusion about the MLE of $\ \theta$? If the MLE exists, what is the systematic way to find its expected value? Any help on these question would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood function is a function of $\theta.$ When $\theta$ is less than any of the $x_i$ it is zero. Thus it is equal to $$\frac{3^n}{\theta^{3n}}(x_1\ldots x_n)^2$$ for $\theta\ge\max(x_i)$ and zero otherwise. Thus its maximum at not zero, but rather at the smallest value of $\theta$ so that $\theta\ge \max(x_i).$ In other words, at $\hat\theta = \max(x_i).$

To find its expected value, you can compute the distribution of $\max(x_i)$ and then integrate. To get the distribution of the max, it's easiest to work with CDFs (and then differentiate to get the PDF).

Comment: thank you very much for your help!! I felt into the trap...:p Is the cdf $P(max(x_i)\leq x) = (\frac{x}{\theta})^{3n}$ for $x\leq \theta$, and $= 1$ for $x > \theta$ ? But then wouldn't the pdf $=(3n)\frac{x^{3n-1}}{\theta^{3n}}$?

Comment: @user177196 Yes that looks right.

Comment: so the expected value of $\hat{\theta}$ would be $\frac{3n}{\theta^{3n}}\int_{0}^{\theta} x_{i}^{3n-1}x_i\ dx_i$?

Comment: my apology, but could you please help give this problem a look http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190476/convergence-of-mle-for-i-i-d-sample-with-pdf-fx-mid-theta-theta-x-theta?rq=1

Comment: @user177196 yep, don't doubt yourself, just do the integral and make sure the answer looks reasonable.

Comment: @user177196 if you're wondering what 'looks reasonable', remember $\hat\theta$ is a MLE so it's probably a good estimator for $\theta.$ In particular, as $n$ gets large it should become unbiased. In other words $E(\hat\theta)\to \theta$

Comment: thank you so much for your patience. I got $\frac{3n\theta}{3n+1}$, which indeed converges to $\theta$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$:) Thanks a ton!!